# Regex C# replace matched fields with multiple results

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have this text:

`iif(instr(|Wellington, New Zealand|,|,|)>0,|Wellington, New Zealand|,|Wellington, New Zealand| & |, | & |New Zealand|) & | to | & iif(instr(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|,|)>0,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia| & |, | & |Saudi Arabia|) & iif(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|=||,||,| via | & |Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|)`

I can regex the text (below) to get a collection of all of the elements between the `|` characters.  I get 18 matches, with match #1 being `|,|`

```
MatchCollection fields = Regex.Matches(str, @"\|.*?\|");
```

I then want to replace each of the matches with a place holder like `~0~`, `~1~`, `~2~` etc up to `~17~` so I can run the rest of my code.  I don't care if all of the common text is replaced with the same place holder which would leave gaps in the place holders if I use all 18.

My problem is that I can't just do a straight replace as replacing element #1 (`|,|`) in this part of the string `|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|,|` will replace the first instance it finds, where regex correctly recognizes `|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|` as one match and `|,|` as another match.

The result I seek is this:

`iif(instr(~0~,~1~)>0,~0~,~0~ & ~2~ & ~3~) & ~4~ & iif(instr(~5~,~1~)>0,~5~,~5~ & ~2~ & ~6~) & iif(~5~=~7~,~7~,~8~ & ~5~)`

with the increasing numbers being in an array that I build once I know how many matches I have.  I keep the original values and swap them back later on which is the easy part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use some lambda functions:

```
// This one gets the index from the list of matches
private static string LookupReplace(string text, List<string> newList)
{
    var result = "~" + newList.IndexOf(text).ToString() + "~";
    return result;
}

// This one just increments a global counter
private static string NumberedReplace()
{
    i++;
    return "~" + i.ToString() + "~";
}

public static int i = -1;

public static void Main()
{   
    string text = "iif(instr(|Wellington, New Zealand|,|,|)>0,|Wellington, New Zealand|,|Wellington, New Zealand| & |, | & |New Zealand|) & | to | & iif(instr(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|,|)>0,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia| & |, | & |Saudi Arabia|) & iif(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|=||,||,| via | & |Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|)";
    var re = new Regex(@"\|.*?\|");
    var newList = re.Matches(text)
                    .OfType<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value)
                    .ToList();
    // First replace with index
    string result = re.Replace(text, x => LookupReplace(x.Value, newList));
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    // Second replace with counter
    result = re.Replace(text, x => NumberedReplace());
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/XDZSNI)

Output of each replace:

```
iif(instr(~0~,~1~)>0,~0~,~0~ & ~4~ & ~5~) & ~6~ & iif(instr(~7~,~1~)>0,~7~,~7~ & ~4~ & ~12~) & iif(~7~=~14~,~14~,~16~ & ~7~)
iif(instr(~0~,~1~)>0,~2~,~3~ & ~4~ & ~5~) & ~6~ & iif(instr(~7~,~8~)>0,~9~,~10~ & ~11~ & ~12~) & iif(~13~=~14~,~15~,~16~ & ~17~)
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry - your first way of doing it is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

```
\|,\|(?=[^(|]*(\|[^(|]*\|)*[^(|]*\))
```

You can use a `lookahead` to check if `|,|` being captured for replace leaves no stray `|` before `)`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/14

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... a bit hard to explain but basically building from what you got...

Given the **matches**, I add them to a list and get unique matches using `Distinct` LINQ function and sort them descending longest to shortest using `OrderBy` LINQ function.  Then just loop through the resulting **RouteMap** and do replace on the original string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "iif(instr(|Wellington, New Zealand|,|,|)>0,|Wellington, New Zealand|,|Wellington, New Zealand| & |, | & |New Zealand|) & | to | & iif(instr(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|,|)>0,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia| & |, | & |Saudi Arabia|) & iif(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|=||,||,| via | & |Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|)";

        Console.WriteLine(input);

        var re = new Regex(@"\|.*?\|");

        var matches = re.Matches(input);

        var mz = new List<string>();

        foreach(Match m in matches) 
        {
            mz.Add(m.Groups[0].ToString());
        }

        var routeMap = mz.Distinct().OrderByDescending(n => n.Length).ToList(); //Get distinct, and sort it longest to shortest... need it this way or it won't do the replacement correctly.

        for (var i = 0; i < routeMap.Count; i++) 
        {
            input = input.Replace(routeMap[i], string.Format("~{0}~", i));          
        }

        Console.WriteLine(input);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The route map replacement key:");
        var idx = 0;
        routeMap.ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", idx++, m));

    }
}
```

Running sample at:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/PIuuae

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a suggestion to obtain your 2nd output option.

You can use a `MatchEvaluator` to pass the match to a separate method, and increase a "global" counter inside that method:

```
    public string ReplaceMatch(Match m)
    {
        i++;
        return "~" + i.ToString() + "~";

    }
    public static int i = -1;
    // ... then, in your calling method

    var txt = "iif(instr(|Wellington, New Zealand|,|,|)>0,|Wellington, New Zealand|,|Wellington, New Zealand| & |, | & |New Zealand|) & | to | & iif(instr(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|,|)>0,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia| & |, | & |Saudi Arabia|) & iif(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|=||,||,| via | & |Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|)";
    var fields = Regex.Matches(txt, @"\|.*?\|");
    var txt2 = Regex.Replace(txt, @"\|.*?\|", new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceMatch));
```

Output:

```
iif(instr(~0~,~1~)>0,~2~,~3~ & ~4~ & ~5~) & ~6~ & iif(instr(~7~,~8~)>0,~9~,~10~ & ~11~ & ~12~) & iif(~13~=~14~,~15~,~16~ & ~17~)
```

[image]

The match values that correspond to those placeholders are held in `fields` variable, so later you will be able to match them.

**EDIT**: For Option 1 (that is the only option after you edited the question), the answer is to create a Dictionary with distinct items, and use that in the replacement method:

```
var txt = "iif(instr(|Wellington, New Zealand|,|,|)>0,|Wellington, New Zealand|,|Wellington, New Zealand| & |, | & |New Zealand|) & | to | & iif(instr(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|,|)>0,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|,|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia| & |, | & |Saudi Arabia|) & iif(|Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|=||,||,| via | & |Jeddah, Saudi Arabia|)";
var fields = Regex.Matches(txt, @"\|.*?\|").Cast<Match>().Select(p=> p.Value).Distinct().Select((s, i) => new { s, i }).ToDictionary(x => x.s, x => x.i);
var txt3 = Regex.Replace(txt, @"\|.*?\|", m => string.Format("~{0}~", fields[m.Value]));
```

Output:

```
iif(instr(~0~,~1~)>0,~0~,~0~ & ~2~ & ~3~) & ~4~ & iif(instr(~5~,~1~)>0,~5~,~5~ & ~2~ & ~6~) & iif(~5~=~7~,~7~,~8~ & ~5~)
```

Comment: Thanks but I have tested more and the second option fails my code later on.  I need to return the first option which I have now edited to show.

Comment: I have added the solution for the current output. Looks like just 2 lines :)

Comment: Thanks for your second suggestion - I had tried Jerrys suggestion & gone to bed by the time you posted.  Yours looks very elegant as well. Cheers

Comment: I see. I am also using lambdas BTW. Jerry just splits the code into a separate method, while I am putting all the LINQ expressions on 1 line, and use the lambda in the MatchEvaluator.